# PS1 command substitution fails when containing newlines on msys bash

Tags: bash, backticks, ps1, command-substitution

This command succeeds

```
$ PS1='$(date +%s) $ '
1391380852 $
```

However if I add a newline it fails

```
$ PS1='$(date +%s)\n$ '
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `date +%s)'
```

If I use backticks it works

```
$ PS1='`date +%s`\n$ '
1391381008
$
```

but [backticks are discouraged](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082). So what is causing this error?

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(6)-release
```

Comment: It works fine for me. What bash version are you using? I have `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(2)-release` installed.

Comment: It's work for me too even with bash 3 and KSH (besides the `\n` with KSH).

Comment: Any particular vendor package of 4.2.45(6), or is this stock upstream?

Comment: It's hard to imagine which a character which **follows** the closing parenthesis causes that parenthesis to be considered a literal part of the command being substituted, rather than a closing token for command substitution. The parsing must be convoluted, making backward jumps in the stream, or bizarre lookaheads.

Comment: @Kaz, `))` is a different token from `)`, so some amount of lookahead is mandatory. But yes, this is a funny one -- that it's platform-dependent makes it doubly so.

Comment: This is a weird & esoteric problem. I just hit something similar all these years later, in Git bash on Windows.... I just resorted to using backticks. If it works...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can disambiguate the parsing easily, to prevent hitting any such bug (though I can't reproduce it myself):

```
PS1='$(date +%s)'$'\n$ '
```

This `$'\n'` syntax parses to a literal newline character, whereas `'\n'` parses to a string containing a two-character `\n` escape sequence.

For more info on how `$''` differs from `''` (expanding backslash-escaped sequences) refer to the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings).

Comment: Works like a charm. The problem arose in my case using MSYS2 compiled bash `(GNU bash, version 4.2.45(6)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)`). Thank you.

Comment: Using newest version of Git for Windows with Git Bash - needed to edit `%USERDIR%/.profile` and change lines 8 and 18 using this answer. E.g. line 8 was `PS1='\[\e]0;${PWD##*/}\a\]\n'` and needed changed to `PS1='\[\e]0;${PWD##*/}\a\]'$'\n'` and now I don't get the substitution errors. Thank you, sir.

Comment: @JustGoscha, could you post a log, copy-and-pasted, showing you running this code and the resulting behavior in a gist? (That is, actually doing the assignment to PS1 on the command line, just to be sure we aren't seeing any interaction from other dotfile contents).

Comment: Okay, actually this code works. But I have the double quotation marks in my example and my code goes over several lines. And I don't know how to escape the \n in this case. Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/Jaym3ARk

Comment: Okay I solved it for double quotes `"bla \n bla"` becomes `"bla "$'\n'" bla"`. Solved by good old trial and error, and reading about Bash escaping...

Comment: @JustGoscha, ...btw, pastebin.com is awful for anyone without adblock; I suggested gist for a reason.

Comment: This is so weird. The same prompt works on Mac, Linux and Cygwin, but not in MSYS. Splitting the string with quotes, and inserting the $ char, fixes it, but I have no idea why. The explanation given by Duffy is not really helping as it does not reflect the code - where is the `$''` bit in the actual code?

Comment: @oligofren, do you see `$'\n$ '` in my answer? Look a bit closer if not. `$''` is part of the *workaround*, not the bug.

Comment: @oligofren, ...one thing to keep in mind is that shell doesn't require a word to have the same quoting style the same way through; you can do, for instance, `literal"double-quoted"'single-quoted'` to generate a single word, different parts of which are treated with three different quoting types at parse time. That's exactly what I'm doing in the answer, switching to the `$''` quoting type to inject a literal newline.

Comment: I understood both points, but not how the extra $ changes anything. I am not sure how the $ gets parsed to be frank. It surely does not get parsed to a literal $ sign. And not how it can affect the following newline either. I see it does, of course...

Comment: @oligofren, it's a different quoting form that causes things to be parsed differently. `$'\n'` parses to a one-character literal newline, whereas `'\n'` parses to a two-character sequence, a literal backslash followed by a literal `n`.

Comment: Ah, now that makes sense! It modifies parsing by doing (some/full?) evaluation of the string. That should be part of the answer.

Comment: @oligofren, "evaluation of the string"? I find that phrase misleading, since it performs only a very specific kinds of expansion, not general-purpose evaluation. There are no `$()` expansions, no `$foo` expansions... really, nothing but your backslash-escape-sequence replacement with literals. And the answer **already does indicate** that it does that; to quote the last paragraph: "This `$''` syntax places a literal newline inside the variable's contents, rather than a `\n` escape sequence." -- I don't know how I could make it more clear.

Comment: @oligofren, ..."evaluation" typically means something more like what `eval` performs, which is absolutely not the case here. `$''` is a literal syntax (that is, a syntax used to express literals), not an expansion type.

Comment: No, that last sentence is what got me confused. If it had said $ will do backslash expansion on the following single quoted string that would be perfectly clear.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about wrong term usage. What you said :)

Comment: Just to be clear, if instead of "This $'' syntax..." had said "This $'\n ' syntax..."  I would not have gotten confused :-)

Comment: Thank you -- hopefully the edit now applied meets with your approval.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123580/discussion-between-oligofren-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with `.git-prompt` when I tried to include it in my PS1 on bash (MSYS2) on Windows. The problem is the `\n`, if I remove it everything run smoothly but I want to break-line.

By the way on Linux everything is working fine.

The `bash` is run is: `4.3.42(5)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)`

*Old, problematic PS1:*

```
PS1='\e[32m\]\u@\h \e[36m\]\w \e[32m\]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")\nλ \e[0m\]$(tput sgr0)'
```

*Fixed:*

```
PS1='\e[32m\]\u@\h \e[36m\]\w \e[32m\]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")'$'\nλ \e[0m\]'
```

*Simplified version (no colors, copy-paste-edit it):*

```
PS1='\u@\h \w $(__git_ps1 "(%s)")'$'\n$ '
```

Cheers [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) finding the problem!

Answer (score 2):

The `$'\n'` hack was still resulting in a syntax error for me in my git-bash Windows VSCode terminal. After a lot of trial and error, I managed to fix it by using the octal equivalent of the newline character, which is `\012`.

In short, replace `\n` with `\012` wherever it's giving you a syntax error.