# Why does a newline in PS1 throw a syntax error in Git for Windows bash?

Tags: windows, git, bash

I am trying to set my user prompt in the [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) Bash prompt. Here's a (very simple) prompt that works:

```
# \@                 Prints the time: 11:14 AM
# \w                 Prints the full cwd path
# $(__git_ps1 ...)   Prints the current git branch

PS1='\n[\@] \w $(__git_ps1 "(%s)") \$ '
```

As soon as I add a second newline character into the mix, I get the following error:

```
 bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token ')'
 bash: command substitution: line 1: `__git_ps1 "(%s)")'
```

The variant of the prompt that throws this error is (note the newline before the `$` prompt):

```
PS1='\n[\@] \w $(__git_ps1 "(%s)") \n\$ '
```

I'm thinking there must be an issue with the `__git_ps1` routine that's causing this issue to occur, but I don't really understand it. Is there something simple here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, it turns out that this has [already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517281/ps1-command-substitution-fails-when-containing-newlines-on-msys-bash).

By using [quoted string expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html#STRQ), one can avoid the problem:

```
PS1='\n[\@] \w $(__git_ps1 "(%s)")'$'\n\$ '
```

It's amazing to me that in 2016 Bash still uses this terrible, terrible syntax. There has to be a better way.

Comment: the difference is the `'$'` near the end, refer to https://www.diffchecker.com/qq8HJsjy