# How do I embed both a command and new line into my custom bash prompt?

Tags: bash, git-bash, ps1

I am working in git-bash on windows and I am trying to configure my bash prompt so that it displays like:

```
username: <custom abbreviated form of pwd>
$
```

To generate my custom abbreviated form of pwd I was going to substitute my own custom script into PS1 as follows:

```
PS1="\u: \$(<custom_script.sh>) \n \$ "
```

However, this PS1 definition seems to generate error messages each time a new prompt is displayed. **What is interesting is this error does not appear when the new line character is removed!**

For example, consider the test I did using the date command:

```
$ PS1="\u: \$(date) \$ "
Former: Wed, Apr 18, 2018  5:09:37 PM $
Former: Wed, Apr 18, 2018  5:09:42 PM $ PS1="\u: \$(date) \n \$ "
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `date)'
Former:
$
```

*Prompt dislays fine when \n isn't before the \$, but gives error messages when included.*

**How do I get rid of the error messages?**

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897021/why-does-a-newline-in-ps1-throw-a-syntax-error-in-git-for-windows-bash

Comment: Seems odd that this is still a bug.

Comment: Ahhh.... thanks guys!